# How can I shorten if else statement inside every() callback function?

Tags: javascript

I would like to shorten following code:

```
const tickersValid = arrayStocks.every((ticker) => {
    const { error } = schemaTicker.validate(ticker);
    if(error) {
         // console.log('Joi error msg:', error.details[0].message);
         return false
    } else {
         return true;
    }
});
```

I tried `(error) ? true : false` which didn't work.

Comment: "_[D]idn't work_" in what way? The conditional statement seems to be the opposite of what you have in your if-statement.

Comment: ```(error) ? false : true``` doesn't work either.

Comment: If you `return` that, it should work in exactly the same way as your current `if` statement.

Comment: Did you remeber to prefix that with a `return` => `return (error) : false : true`?

Comment: thanks for the help. ```return (error) ? false : true;``` did work. I forgot the ```return```.

Comment: Purely for the sake of interest, this could be further cut down to something like `const tickersValid = arrayStocks.every(ticker => !schemaTicker.validate(ticker)?.error)`, but at that point you are starting to sacrifice readability so it would be better to avoid too much code reduction and go with one of the answers below.

Comment: @Nothere what you wanted is the opposite of a boolean which you can do like that `!anyboolean` just put `!` before any boolean to get opposite value of boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want simplify your piece of code. If error is true you return false and when error is false you return true, so, you return !error.

Simplify in this way:

```
return (!error);
```

Anyway, inside every callback you can set bool variable and return it. Simply example:

```js
const func = function(){
  let res = false;
  //... imagine complex condition
  condition ? res = true : res = false;
  //retur res. 
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean this?

```
    const { error } = schemaTicker.validate(ticker);
    return !error;
```

Comment: even better. I thought error is an object here.

Comment: please note an empty object is actually `truthy`. Make sure you don't have unexpected behaviour